# Installing Jupyter Notebook upgrades my python version

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I need to user Jupyter Notebook with python version 3.5.

When I create a new environment,with a specific version of python, it works properly

```
conda create -n newenv python=3.5
```

If I type `python`in the prompt, I have the proper version

```
 C:\Users\Arthur>python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

However, if I install jupyter notebook in the conda GUI, it will automatically switch my python version to the last one

```
(newenv) C:\Users\Arthur>python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan  2 2019, 17:07:39) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

How can I prevent this ?